# Facebook - Pasted Website Links Not Displaying Story OR Thumbnail - Suddenly Stopped

Tags: facebook

I manage my Facebook page (/wrestlingedge) and since last week when I paste links from my site into the Status box on the page, it will not pull the story or thumbnail and I am not sure why - this has always worked fine previously and nothing has changed on the Website. Here is a screenshot of what happens - it doesn't even seem to attempt to pull the information - https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t39.2229/851586_10153839130105416_669227132_n.jpg

Now here is the odd thing, if I add a URL and knock off the trailing '/' at the end of the URL it works OR if I run the entire URL (with the trailing slash) through the debugger it then also works regardless what I paste in. That said, when it works, it only pulls through the image in small format so the title / description displays beside it rather than below the big image which is what I want.

So for example, let take: http://wrestling-edge.com/tna-impact-report-2202014/

If I paste in URL/tna-impact-report-2202014/ it will NOT work

If I paste in URL/tna-impact-report-2202014 it WILL work

If I run URL/tna-impact-report-2202014/ through the debugger that URL will work

I can't work out what's happening and as I said, nothing has changed on the site.

it's inconvenient to run the URL through a debugger constantly and I don't like adding the URL without a trailing slash as that belongs on the URL. Also, I would like the image to display in large format too. I can only think this is some kind of FB error as I see nothing in the debugger in terms of warning messages etc. either. The code in the debugger pulls the title, description and image (large size) just fine, so I am a little stuck.

I've tried to get an answer via Facebook, but with no success.

Regards

Amish

Comment: Not sure but it works for me and the debugger does not show any error and looks like you have all the correct org tags.

Comment: it works now because you put the URL through the debugger as I said in my original post. If you take another link WITHOUT putting it through the debugger it won't work - http://wrestling-edge.com/del-rio-wants-wwe-world-heavyweight-title-shot-jr-taker-vs-lesnar-real-americans/ for example.

Comment: Well I just tried on FB (not debugger) without the trailing slash / and it works image and descriptions are getting shown. Also in your source code I see the canonical and URL having a trailing slash.. try remove that that and see if this changes.

Comment: Yep, like I said, it works without the trailing slash / but it doesn't show the image in big format when it's posted (it does in preview weirdly).

Will check re. the slashes

Comment: without the trailing slash i.e. http://wrestling-edge.com/del-rio-wants-wwe-world-heavyweight-title-shot-jr-taker-vs-lesnar-real-americans

Comment: You can avoid this by adding a 301 redirect by htaccess, so when FB fatches the URL it gets 301 redirect URL without trailing slash

Comment: Hmm I don't really want to do that. What I don't understand is that it worked previously with AND without the trailing slash, and nothing has changed on the site.

Comment: Yes its weird !! I am also sure that nothing got changed in the GRAPH URL in last few days.

Comment: Thanks anyway! If anyone else has any thoughts on the cause, please let me know :)

Comment: sure I will check with my team here they are quite experienced with FB apps may be they can have some answer.